# Can browser functions queued with setTimeouts be abandoned automatically?

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome, browser, settimeout

I have a recursive polling function that does some stuff and then calls itself with a setTimeout of 100 ms. However, if I call another synchronous function that does some stuff for a long time while the recursive polling function is running, I assume the function called with a setTimeout of 100ms will be queued, but if that long function does not return within a specified amount of time, will the browser simply discard the queued function? I'm asking this because it seems that the recursive polling function stops running after this other long running function is called. Also I checked with `console.log`'s that the recursive function reaches and calls the setTimeout but the function passed to setTimeout never is called after the long synchronous function is called. This is all in Chrome 23 and Firefox 15.

Comment: Can you show the code, so we can confirm your assumptions please?

Comment: @alex I would but it's a lot of code with lots of abstractions.

Comment: @alex Maybe a jsfiddle with a contrived example would be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setTimeout` functions cannot be "automatically" cancelled - so long as you allow the browser to return to its event loop they *will* get called.

Should you *want* to have a timer function that cancels itself automatically that should be relatively easy to achieve:

```
window.setTimeoutMaybe = function(f, t0, t1) {
    t1 = t1 || (t0 * 10);
    var then = new Date();
    return window.setTimeout(function() {
        var now = new Date();
        if (now - then < t1) {
            f();
        } 
    }, t0);
};
```

i.e. call `f` after time `t0`, but only if time `t1` hasn't passed.

Comment: what could account for a setTimeout to fail to execute its function after being called then?

Comment: @user730569 AFAIK, only an infinite loop in some other piece of code that blocks the event loop, or an explicit `clearTimeout`.

Comment: Strange because I don't think I have an infinite loop and I definitely do not call `clearTimeout` anywhere

Comment: And as far as I can tell my browser console shows no exceptions that would terminate runtime.

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout(100, funct) will not give you guaranty that after 100ms your function will be executed.

If after 100ms if the browser is doing something else or hung it will wait till it will come back and execute it.

Here

```
function pausecomp(millis)
 {
  var date = new Date();
  var curDate = null;
  do { curDate = new Date(); }
  while(curDate-date < millis);
 }

var time = new Date();

setTimeout(function(){
    var lapse=new Date() -time;
    alert(lapse; 
},100);

pausecomp(300);
```

​
for example program loop for 300ms while 100ms setTimeout was running.
(http://jsfiddle.net/xX2b4/)

If you run it output will be 300+ value as for 300ms system was hung in the loop.